# How to compare 2 lists of different objects with similar properties

Tags: java, hamcrest

If I have 2 instances from 2 different classes as follows (with similar attributes), can I use Hamcrest's `containsInAnyOrder` to match their attributes?

```
class Something{

    int id;
    int name;
}

class GsonSomething{

    int id;
    int name;
}
```

Can I use `containsInAnyOrder` or any other method to compare 2 lists from the 2 classes?

```
List<Something> somethingList; //[ {id:1, name: "one"}, {id:1, name: "two"} ]


List<GsonSomething> gsonSomethingList; //[ {id:1, name: "one"}, {id:1, name: "two"} ]
```

The use case of this is to be used in a test method to compare the result vs the expected. And I used the following approach:

```
for(Something s : somethingList){
    GsonSomething gs = gsonSomethingList.stream().filter(p -> p.id.equals(s.id)).findFirst();
    assertEquals(s.name, gs.name);
    //assert other attributes

}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility of creating a base class and make both `Something` and `GsonSomething` extend it?

Comment: Can just override equals in each class and do some basic checks

Comment: @tgdavies can that be used to compare 2 classes? I tried to use the `samePropertyValuesAs` but it gave me the error `incompatible type`.

Comment: @S.Dan you're correct

Answer (score 3):

Create your own matcher by extending http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/BaseMatcher.html and use it in the assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, no.

### Why not?

Java holds that the type namespace is holy, and everything else is only relative to the type it is in. In other words, in java, these two methods:

```
class Gun() { void shoot(Person p); }

class Camera() { void shoot(Person p); }
```

are considered to be *utterly unrelated*, and the same goes for fields that so happen to have the same name: Does not mean they are related, at all.

### Okay, so how do I do this?

You're going to have to go out of your way to convert your inputs to something that can be compared.

Fortunately, that is relatively simple. Had it been a single property you want to compare (say, the `int id` value), then just convert both values to that and then run your comparison.

If you have 'compound keys' (you want both `id` and `name` to be equal) you need some type that can hold these keys. Presumably both `GsonSomething` and `Something` are themselves qualifying as types that can do the job, so you really just need to convert, say, your list of `GsonSomething` to a list of `Something` and then you can compare.

### But what about my solution

Your solution has two problems.

The glaring one: It's not doing a proper job. If there is an element in gsonSomethingList that does not appear in somethingList at all, your test will still pass, which would be incorrect.

A slightly less problematic one: It is very slow; it's O(n^2) speed. If the inputs start hitting 5 digits (10k entries and up - in that ballpark), you're going to notice. Once they hit 7, this test starts taking extremely long.

### So what is a better way?

To speed up the comparison, these need to be in a set, which requires proper equals and hashcode impls. So let's start there, and make `Something` are class of record:

```
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode
class Something {
    int id;
    int name;
}
```

If [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) is not something you're using, perhaps:

```
class Something {
    int id;
    int name;

    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (other.getClass() != Something.class) return false;
        Something o = (Something) other;
        return o.id == this.id && o.name == this.name;
        // NB: Use .equals() and add null checks if `name` is String!
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return (31 + id) * 31 + name;
    }
}
```

Now that we have that, we can convert one to the other, and use sets, which can do such a job much faster (algorithmically so, in fact):

```
Set<Something> a = ....;
List<GsonSomething> rawB = ...;

Set<Something> b = rawB.stream()
    .map(b -> new Something(b.getId(), b.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.asSet());
```

and now you can use e.g. containsInAnyOrder with `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do some slight refactoring. I would first create a base class, make `Something` and `GsonSomething` class extend it. In the base class I would override the `equals` method.

```
abstract class BaseSomething {
    int id;
    String name; //This should definitely be a String type

   //getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
       if (other == this) return true;
       if (other == null) return false;
       if (!(other instanceof BaseSomething)) return false;
       BaseSomething o = (BaseSomething) other;

       return o.id == this.id && o.name.equals(this.name);
    }
}

class Something extends BaseSomething {
}

class GsonSomething extends BaseSomething {
}
```

Now, this are pretty easy. Your two `List` fields will be now:

```
List<BaseSomething> somethingList; //[ {id:1, name: "one"}, {id:1, name: "two"} ]


List<BaseSomething> gsonSomethingList; //[ {id:1, name: "one"}, {id:1, name: "two"} ]
```

And a simple call to Hamcrest method should do the job:

```
assertThat(gsonSomethingList, containsInAnyOrder(somethingList.toArray(new BaseSomething[0]));
```